# When merging multiple files, first file left out

Tags: r, for-loop, merge

I'm trying to merge all ".txt" files in the wd using R and append the originating filename at the end of each row. Right now I'm running a for loop that looks like this:

```
xfiles = list.files(pattern = "\\.txt$")

combinedfiles = data.frame()

for (currentFile in xfiles){
    filex = read.delim(currentFile,sep="\t",header=T,fill=T)
    filex$File.name = rep(currentFile,nrow(filex))
    combinedfiles = merge(combinedfiles,filex,all=T)
    rm(filex)
}
```

The loop runs, and outputs the ***combinedfiles*** variable correctly, except that every time that it runs, **one file is left out** (e.g. if 4 txt files exist in the wd, only 3 are combined in the output). When one file is in the wd, no rows are merged into combinedfiles, but the column names are added to the blank combinedfiles data frame.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong with this merging?

Thanks!

Comment: Do they always have the same columns? Then you're probably looking to `rbind` them instead of `merge` them.

Comment: Thanks Aaron and MrFlick! Most of the columns are the same (~19/23), but not all. This number is likely to change as upstream processes are changed as well, so merge seemed like the easier solution.

Comment: Also check out `rbind.fill` in the `plyr` package, I believe.

Comment: Nice, rbind.fill is about 9 times faster, and for all intents and purposes seems to give the same output. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you merge with an empty data.frame, no rows are returned, but it does add columns for each of the tables. and since the first table has no columns, it returns columns for the second table.  Observe

```
dd<-data.frame()
d1<-data.frame(a=1:3, b=4:6)
d2<-data.frame(a=1:3, c=4:6)

merge(dd, d1)
# [1] a b
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

merge(merge(dd, d1), d2)
# [1] a b c
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

I'm actually surprised you get any rows at all. Do all these files share a common column to do the merging on? Are you sure `merge`? Is the right operation?

Instead of merging the first data.frame to nothing, you could check if there are existing rows first.

```
for (currentFile in xfiles){
    filex = read.delim(currentFile,sep="\t",header=T,fill=T)
    filex$File.name = rep(currentFile, nrow(filex))
    if( nrow(combinedfiles)>0 ) {
        combinedfiles = merge(combinedfiles,filex,all=T)
    } else {
        combinedfiles = filex
    }
    rm(filex)
}
```

Comment: The `all=TRUE` is why subsequent merges have rows. Agree though that `merge` may not be the right operation. `rbind` sounds more likely.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron. Somehow I missed that even though I copied and pasted it.

Comment: Excellent, worked like a charm!

I chose merge instead of rbind because across the txt files ~19/23 columns are common, but I'd like to retain any column that's present in any file. This seemed to be most easily done with merge.